# Using FET as SPST switch to feed H bridge with boosted voltage

Tags: arduino, transistors, motor, switches, h-bridge

My board uses TTL logic, I have a motorised pot that moves too slowly at 5V. At 9V it performs well, I have little LM2577 replacement modules that output the boosted voltage well, but they consume about 30mA at idle, so I only want it on (and in turn powering the motor) when the motor is supposed to move.

The design below shows essentially what is desired.

[image]

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how I should incorporate this design using a FET or BJT, (have a selection of PNPs and NPNs). Of course I'm open to other design suggestions or ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYA5tT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Remove the two 4.7kOhm resistors, and connect the diodes to A2 and A3. When at least one is at 5V, then it means that you want one of the following conditions:

- Forward (A3 high, A2 low)
- reverse (A2 high, A3 low)
- brake (A2 and A3 both high)

Then, the BA6208 must be powered. The two diodes + R1 form an OR gate, and therefore turn on Q1 if at least one of A2 or A3 is high. The collector goes to 0 V, then the PMOSFET turns on.

If both A2 and A3 are off, Q1 is off, its collector is pulled high to 9V and M1 is off too.

Still, I don't know if continuously applying-removing power to the BA6208 might damage it. A better solution would be the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHBZC.png)</sup>

Then, your program will enable/disable the power, by outputting A4 high/low. 
You should implement a software retriggerable monostable, that is:

- Do I need to move forward/reverse or brake? Put A4 high and reset a timer.
- Have some seconds elapsed since the last forward/reverse/brake operation? Turn off the power, by pulling low A4.

NOTE:
In each schematics M1 must be a 5-V logic level MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks, what's an example of M1? Is where you labelled 'TOBA6208' the V_in to the booster module?

Comment: Since the output current max is only 0.5A (absolute. Typ. 100mA), then an SMD mosfet in SOT23 package should be enough. The cheapest (in 10 quantities) on digikey, with \$ R_{DS,on}<0.2\ \Omega\$ is DMP3099L-7. A through hole pMOSFET: TSM680P06CH X0G. You can also relax the \$ R_{DS,on}<0.2\ \Omega\$ requirement (At 500mA you could choose a \$ R_{DS,on}=1\ \Omega\$ and the SOT-23 package would still stay "cool" enough).

Comment: Yes i meant Vin of the booster. I'm going to edit the schematics to fix this issue.

Comment: Ok great, one confusion remains: you say the second design eliminates the threat/risk of damaging the H bridge through excessive power-cycles, but doesn't the second design also cycle the power to the H bridge as well ?

Comment: Yes, but you dont continuously turn it on and off. Consider this case: in the first circuit, if you make a lot of small movements (and very short pauses), you are continuously power cycling the driver. In the second circuit if the pauses are shorter than the "timeout" period, then you will keep the driver powered. Yes, you'll waste a bit more power, but for "few" seconds. If you do not need any movement for a long time, the timer eventually will timeout, and the driver will be unpowered.

Comment: I understand now, i already do that timer solution to turn off state leds after some seconds. It's a good idea and i'll go with it. 

Question about the MOSFET, I wanted to make sure i don't screw up - is the parameter i care about for it to be 5V controllable the 'minimum gate threshold voltage'?

Comment: It's written on the datasheet. Either "logic level" or, when they write "Rds,on = xyz @ Vgs = 5V" then it's suitable for your 5-V application.

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten around to implementing the design and it works well, but the H bridge died :p it's an odd one but a separate issue so i'll just say what happened, the design worked great, motor spinning fine, but over time it slowed to a halt, so i desoldered the Vcc to the H bridge, thinking it was overheating or some other issue. I temporarily put it back and it worked, then the Vcc pin and wire i was holding temporarily arced, now Vcc and GND is internally bridged. Might need a better H bridge! Not sure if the motor drew too mcuh current, i previously measured < absolute rating.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a P-channel MOSFET: Source to +5V, Drain to load, gate to microcontroller.

You may want to add a high-value pullup resistor from gate to +5V for those cases where the microcontroller pin is tri-stated.

It may also be a good idea to have a 100R resistor in series with the Gate.  Locate that resistor as close to the FET as possible.

Bring the Gate LOW (0V) to turn the load ON.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. next-hacks answer is similar to what you've recommended, i'll be going with this solution.

Comment: Thank you, your answer along with the other worked well. Can i ask, why you chose a P channel over an N channel?